# PHP functions and @functions

Tags: php, operators

Basically, I've seen people using `@` before their function calls, not for every function, but for some kind of extension functions like `file_get_contents()`, `mysql_connect()` and so on.

And yes, the question is: For what purpose are there these `@`s before function calls?

Or in other words, what is the difference between `@file_get_contents()` and `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: See [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does @ mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621215/what-does-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

@ is an [error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). Basically it's suppressing errors.

Answer (score 7):

It's the PHP's [`error control operator`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) used to suppress any error generated by the function call.

Answer (score 2):

The `@` symbol in front of a function prevents errors from being displayed when the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

@function doesn't show any error messages on its HTML output, while a regular function call will.

Comment: @fabrik the same reason as yours. But while yours is ambiguous (just "output"), this one is cleanly states HTML output, which, of course, is a nonsense. Error control has nothing to do with program's output.

Comment: @fabrik: Honestly I do not understand if you are mocking or genuinely asking. Either way I do not care. @Col. Shrapnel: Requesting you to type out your definition of error control for all of us to gain more insight on the subject. I agree that my answer lacks any depth, since I just said what I understood it to be :) Thanks.

Comment: he was talking not to you. But to person who downvoted. Got it now? Error control consists of 2 parts: standard error output *destination* and *level* of error. Both `@` operator and `error_reporting` setting are control *level* of error. (@ sets it to 0) While `log_errors` and `display_errors` settings responsible for the destination. Latter one is responsible for what you have said: HTML output. While @ has nothing to do with it, id should be never used for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

I have similar doubt about @ used in front of functions.
To avoid this I made some verification before the function call.
My example is:

`if ( is_file($filename) )
  $timestamp = filemtime( $filename );`