# When is the '@' operator used in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the use of @ symbol in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-symbol-in-php)
>   [PHP functions and @functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984864/php-functions-and-functions)
>   [What does the “@” symbol do in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361747/what-does-the-symbol-do-in-sql)

Often when looking through online resources / questions including code on this website, I often come across the '@' operator.

In the PHP code I see, the @ operator generally comes before a method such as `@fread()`. However, by the looks of the code, it wouldn't have actually made a difference whether or not `fread()` was called with or without the '@' in front of the method.

In the MySQL code, the @ operator generally comes before a column/field name. I believe that the @ is used to access a default variable instantiated at some point manually by the user, alike to an `env` variable in PHP.

Please can you tell me if my assumptions are correct, and if not, when and why the '@' sign or operator should in fact be used?

Thanks,

Max.

Comment: That's two different questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In PHP it means suppress any notices/warnings raised by this function eg `mail()` will throw an error when it fails to send. You can do

`$Success = @mail(...)`

To suppress the error and handle success/failure yourself.  See the [Error Control Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) page for more information.

In MySQL, `@` is used to prefix [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP the at sign (@) denotes that any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.

In MySQL the @ before a name denotes a local, user-defined variable.