# Why won't a line of code work with error suppressor removed?

Tags: php, error-suppression

I am using PHP classes to connect to a data base. I am unable to solve a problem -- please help me out regarding this.

I have a function:

```
function getCampus($cm_id) //returns campus name
{
    $this->query = "select cm_name from campus where cm_id = ".$cm_id.";";
    $rd = $this->executeQuery();
    @$data = $rd->fetch_assoc();
}
```

and when I remove `@` from  `@$data`, it doesn't work. Please help me out: explain what it is what an alternative way would be. Thanks.

Comment: Define 'it doesnt work'

Comment: Can you give us the error you are getting? PS: I don't know SQL, but you may have to make some of the query string parts uppercase.

Comment: @Tanner I believe the keywords uppercase is a convention and is not strictly enforced.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does @ mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621215/what-does-mean-in-php)

Comment: you should know that `@` only suppresses **warnings** and not fatal errors.

Comment: @Shakti I semi agree with you, because the question is *Why won't a line of code work with error suppressor removed?*

Comment: Show the execute_query method please. I suspect that your issue is there.

Comment: Your API looks like crap to me. Instead of this manually composed stuff (possibly junk, as nothing is preventing that), you should be trying to use placeholders (pg_query_params in Postgres, emulated in Mysql) and you should try to have just one method call with arguments, instead of this assignment followed by a method call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ is used to suppress errors and warnings.

the @ is not your problem

Answer (score 6):

`@` is the error suppressor operator. Using it to prefix a line of code will suppress all non fatal errors. It is a bad idea to use it nearly every time.

If you get no output with it removed, try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL)` in the top of your file or in a bootstrap type file and ensure `display_errors = On` in `php.ini` (you can also use `ini_set('display_errors', 'on')`).

Comment: @thephpdeveloper That edit changed a fair bit of what I said. Now it doesn't say that using `@` is a bad idea, and no mention of `display_errors = on` in `php.ini` which is sometimes an issue.

Answer (score 2):

The `@` symbol in front of commands is used to ignore any errors that happen during the execution.

That line of code still fails when you put a `@` in front of it, but you don't see it. Try to figure out what the problem with `$rd->fetch_assoc()` is. Also, the query looks rather wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The `@` when used in a PHP expression suppresses errors for that expression. So, chances are "it's not working" because `$rd->fetch_assoc()` is throwing an exception.